# Add textfield and checkbox on tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, checkbox, tableview, textfield

In my Iphone app I have to add textfield at two rows of tableview and a checkbox to one row. Can anyone provide me an example that can help me. I am new on Iphone and I don't know how to start with this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you should learn Custom Cell for UITableView first...

Comment: what have you tried ? did you create table by programmatically or using IB ?

Comment: I created the table using IB..I tried to add a textfield but nothing happens

Comment: Something like this, should it work?   if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            UITextField *labl=[[UITextField alloc] init];
            labl.text=@"data";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:labl];

        }

Comment: what you want to do exactly? please clear your question. what you want to make?

Comment: I have to do something like this : http://i55.tinypic.com/o9fuva.png

Comment: where code,ville must have some textfield to introduce them...understand now?

Comment: the table row count is fix or variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as per your comment try this :

```
if(indexPath.row==1)
{
  UITextField *labl=[[UITextField alloc] init];
  // where is your text field's frame ???? 
  labl.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
  labl.text=@"data"; 
  [cell addSubview:labl]; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. It may work, but views added this way will generally _not_ position appropriately during cell transitions into and out of editing mode and in general is hacky. `UITableViewCell contentView` property was created specifically for adding subviews to a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Hey try this one in your  cellForRowAtindexPath

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellID%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]];
if (!cell){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellID%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]] autorelease];  
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if(indexPath.row == 0){
            //  NSString *daytime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"day"];
            UITextField *text0 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 12, 120, 22)];
            text0.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            text0.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            text0.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
            text0.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
            text0.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
            text0.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            text0.delegate = self;
            text0.text = @"Type de Parteneria";
            [cell addSubview:text0];

            UITextField *text1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 160, 20)];
            text1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            text1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
            text1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            text1.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
            text1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            text1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:114.0f/255.0f green:136.0f/255.0f blue:165.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
            text1.delegate = self;

            [cell addSubview:text1];

    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1){
            //  NSString *daytime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"day"];
            UITextField *text0 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 12, 120, 22)];
            text0.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            text0.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            text0.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
            text0.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
            text0.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
            text0.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            text0.delegate = self;
            text0.text = @"Audi R8";
            [cell addSubview:text0];


            UIButton *signBtn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
        signBtn.frame = CGRectMake(15, 170, 290, 35);
        [signBtn setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [signBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [signBtn setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
        [signBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cell addSubview:signBtn];
    }
   return cell;
```

}

If you get problem than message me